# How to use complex curly braces in external template file

Tags: php

I am trying to interpolate a string from an external file but I am having issues using complex curly braces. The variables do not populate as expected? If i take the code from the external template file it successfully returns a value for each variable.

index.php

```
function getIncludeContents($included_file_path, $post){
    
    if ( !file_exists( __DIR__ . $file ) ) {
        return 'nofile';
    }
    
    if ( is_array( $post ) ){
        extract( $post );
    }
    
    ob_start(); 
    include($included_file_path);
    return ob_get_clean();
}

$navigation = getIncludeContents('layouts/test.php', $post);
var_dump($navigation);
```

test.php

```
<div id="post-{$post['id']}"></div>
```

this returns...
`'<div id="post-${post['id']}"></div>'`

when it should return...
`'<div id="post-201"></div>`

any ideas why? thanks

Comment: `extract` create variable based on keys in the array. So  `'<div id="post-{$post['id']}"></div>'` will become `'<div id="post-{$id}"></div>'` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `test.php` doesn't have `<?php`, it's being treated as fixed text, not PHP code to execute. It needs `echo` statements to echo variables, or you can use the short echo tag.

```
<div id="post-<?= $post['id'] ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, ok well that makes sense now. I would say that's the problem solved but before I do I forgot to mention (my bad) that I really wanted to keep the curly braces in as my plan is to use the same file for JavaScript templates; which coincidentally uses the same call for string interpolation/template variables. Do you think there is any way around this? if not then fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<div id="post-<?php echo $post['id']?>"></div>
```